# while (true) loop only activates upon receiving data from IRC socket, not Telegram socket

Tags: php, bash, sockets, telegram

OK, this is a big problem of mine and I've spent over an hour creating a working example so I'm hoping someone out there can sympathise enough with my problem enough to give some help or feedback. 
I am prepared to give you bash access to a centos system running php 5.4 so you can test the code yourself and I'll even invite you into the telegram group "test chat" so you can see results for yourself. If you accept donations I'm prepared to donate $$$$$$ just name your price.

Here's scenario:
I'm running a communications bot that connects to irc and telegram. The idea is people type !uptime in the chat channel (`#public` on `irc.glx-alliance.com:6668`) and in Telegram group `test chat` and the bot tells them how long they have been online for. The example is working, both IRC and TG return uptime stats upon request through `!uptime` command. So far so good.

Here's the problem:
When i type `!uptime` in the IRC client, i get a super fast 0.02 seconds response time. Excellent. That works. However for the Telegram integration, `!uptime` can take up to 30 seconds to respond. The reason why is below.

Some more details:
The initiator for Telegram responding is not that the loop is checking very slowly, but that IRC has sent data to the IRC connection. Which then prompts the telegram code to run. I can reproduce this easily by simply typing into the chat channel and immediately the Telegram test chat channel receives the uptime response.

Here's my working example. For this to work, you will need to open port `6668` in your firewall, have `telegram-cli` installed and be running it from a directory with telegram-cli-php installed. See https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client. Simply type `composer require zyberspace/telegram-cli-client` in the project directory and crete a `telegramIntegrations.php` file in an `includes` directory with the call to vendor.php in there. (`require('vendor/autoload.php');`). My phone number is +447935499706 add to me telegram and I'll invite you to the `test chat` group.

Here's the code. Short of playing [code golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) I can't get the file size down any further. I will describe the important bits after the code itself.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
global $configure;
$configure = array(
    'server' => 'irc.glx-alliance.com',
    'port' => 6668,
    'nick' => 'ExampleBot',
    'name' => 'Example Bot'
);
include_once('../includes/telegramIntegration.php');

class IRCBot{
        // TCP connection holder.
        public $socket;

        // Message holder.
        public $msg = array();

        /*
         * Constucter.
         * Opens the server connection, and logs in the bot.
         *
         * @param array.
         */
        function __construct($configure){
            echo '-----------Socket opening...----------------------------------' ."\r\n";
            $this->socket = fsockopen($configure['server'], $configure['port']);
            $this->login($configure);
            $this->timestamp = time();
            $this->main();
        }

        /*
         * Logs bot in to server
         *
         * @param array.
         */
        function login ($configure){
                $this->send_data('USER', $configure['nick'] . ' rogues-alliance.com ' . $configure['nick'] . ' :' . $configure['name']);
                $this->send_data('NICK', $configure['nick']);
    }

    /*
     * Startup commands
     */
    function startup () {
        echo 'Startup initiated...' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Startup finished' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /*
     * Bot Command
     */
    function intel () { 
        return $this->intel;
    }

    /*
     * Main function, used to grab all data.
     */
    function main(){
            while (true):

                    /* Fetch Data From Telegram Socket */
                    $this->telegram = new \Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\Client('unix:///tmp/tg.sck');


                    /* Fetch Data From IRC Socket */
                    $data = fgets($this->socket, 1024);
                    flush();
                    $data = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/ ', ' ', $data) . PHP_EOL;
                    $this->ex = explode(' ', $data);

                    /* Ping Pong */
                    if($this->ex[0] == 'PING'):
                        $this->send_data('PONG', $this->ex[1]);
                    endif;

                    /* Internal While Loops */
                    if (!$this->firstRun) {
                        $this->firstRun = true;
                        // do some stuff
                    }
                    if ($this->inited){ // have we had the server motd etc
                    }

                    /* Format Text */
                    $command = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $this->ex[3]);
                    if (strtoupper($this->ex[1]) == $this->ex[1]):
                        $request = $this->ex[1];
                    endif;


                    /* Handle Text from IRC $data */
                    switch ($request):
                        case 'PRIVMSG':
                            /* Setup Variables */
                            $host = $this->ex[0]; 
                            $username = substr($host, 1, strpos($host, '!')-1);
                            $target = $this->ex[2];

                            // list of commands the bot responds to
                            switch ($command){  
                                case ':!uptime':
                                    $this->sendMessage($this->uptime());
                                    break;
                                break;
                                case ':!help':
                                        $this->sendMessage('Available commands: !uptime', $this->ex[2]);
                                break;                       
                            }
                            break;
                        case '372':
                        case '375':
                        case '265':
                        case '255':
                        case '254':
                        case '003':
                        case '002':
                            echo $text;
                            break;
                        case '376':

                            /* Startup Commands */
                            $this->startup();
                            break;
                        case 'QUIT':
                            break;
                        default:
                    endswitch;

                    /* Handle Text From Telegram $telegram */
                    if (!$channels)
                        $channels = array(
                            'test chat'
                        );
                        foreach ($channels as $channel):
                            if (!$this->_tgData[$channel]):
                                $this->_tgData[$channel] = $this->telegram->getHistory($channel, 1);
                                $this->_tgData[$channel] = substr($this->_tgData[$channel], strpos($this->_tgData[$channel], ']')+3);
                            endif;

                            // fetch data
                            $this->_history[$channel] = $this->telegram->getHistory($channel, 1, 0);
                            $this->_history[$channel] = substr($this->_history[$channel], strpos($this->_history[$channel], ']')+3);
                            flush();

                            $b=0;
                            $output = array();
                            while (str_replace('>>>' , '', str_replace('»»»', '', str_replace('«««', '',  str_replace('<<<', '', $this->_tgData[$channel])))) != str_replace('>>>' , '', str_replace('»»»', '', str_replace('«««', '',  str_replace('<<<', '', $this->_history[$channel]))))):

                                // fetch data
                                $this->_history[$channel] = $this->telegram->getHistory($channel, 1, $b);
                                $this->_history[$channel] = substr($this->_history[$channel], strpos($this->_history[$channel], ']')+3);    
                                flush();

                                if (preg_match("/(.+) [«><»]{3} (![\w\d]+) (.+)/", $this->_history[$channel], $matches)):
                                    $username = substr(str_replace($channel, '', $matches[1]), 1); 
                                    $command = $matches[2];
                                    $tokens = explode(' ', $matches[3]);

                                    switch($command):
                                        case '!uptime':
                                            echo 'got here';
                                            $this->telegram->msg($channel, $this->uptime());

                                    endswitch;
                                endif;

                                $b++;
                            endwhile;

                        endforeach;
            endwhile;
    }

    function sendMessage ($message, $to = false){
            $this->send_data("PRIVMSG", (!$to?$this->ex[2]:$to) . " :" . $message);
    }
    /*
     * Sends data to the server.
     */
    function send_data($cmd, $msg = null){
        if($msg == null){
               fputs($this->socket, $cmd . "\n");
        } else {
               fputs($this->socket, $cmd.' '.$msg."\n");
        }
    }

    function uptime () {
        echo '------time-----';
        $days = round((time() - $this->timestamp)/60/60/24);
        $hours = round((time() - $this->timestamp)/60/60%24);
        $minutes = round((time() - $this->timestamp)/60%60);
        echo $this->timestamp;
        echo '---time----';
        return "I have been online for $days days, $hours hours and $minutes minutes";
    }
}
$bot = new IRCBot($configure);              
?>
```

So the important parts of the code are as follows:

`while (true): /*code*/ endwhile;`

```
/* Fetch Data From Telegram Socket */
$this->telegram = new \Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\Client('unix:///tmp/tg.sck');

/* Fetch Data From IRC Socket */
$data = fgets($this->socket, 1024);
flush();
```

Data is fetched from IRC socket and Telegram socket, but the IRC socket is receiving data at this point, telegram has to make an additional call to receive data. See below.

```
$this->_tgData[$channel] = $this->telegram->getHistory($channel, 1);
$this->_tgData[$channel] = substr($this->_tgData[$channel], strpos($this->_tgData[$channel], ']')+3);
```

Telegram picks its data up here.

So that covers everything I can think of. I will be using the "show this question to a friend" feature so please no posts about how it's too much code; I have explained the relevant parts so please go easy. Also, the code could not be any shorter if I tried. This is a complete example case and I'm prepared to offer you an environment to test within, for which I will donate to you or a charity of your choosing.

Also please note: can someone create the tags telegram-cli and telegram-cli-php, both are very useful projects to the community.

Comment: Guys I finally found the solution. This took a year to figure out and ?I had to put up with the problem. Network Services were asking me for version information which caused a delay until the "next request" was given. So check your responses from the server on connect in order to fix this if you have the same "hanging" issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the result was to change MySQL session lifetime to something more apt.